# Customizing ShareThis message works on Twitter, but not any other method?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, twitter, sharethis

I'm trying to get a custom message to post to social networks using ShareThis. I'm using the st_title tag for the custom message. I removed all og metadata, reading that that might compete with it. For some reason, the Twitter share is working as expected, while all other shares do not use the custom message.

Any ideas for things to try here? I'm not sure what else to try. Thank you -

Here's the code, whittled down for generalness to the Twitter (working) and Facebook (not working) shares, below. If it's helpful and okay to post, my actual test page is https://critter.co/home/test (click on the 'Instant Inspiration' text to get a modal where you share inspiration).

```
<span class="st_facebook_hcount" st_url="https://critter.co" st_title="Do not overrate what you have received, nor envy others. He who envies others does not obtain peace of mind. - Buddha" displaytext="share" st_processed="yes"><span style="text-decoration:none;color:#000000;display:inline-block;cursor:pointer;" class="stButton"><span><span class="stMainServices st-facebook-counter" style="background-image: url(https://ws.sharethis.com/images/facebook_counter.png);">&nbsp;<img src="https://ws.sharethis.com/images/check-big.png" style="position: absolute; top: -7px; right: -7px; width: 19px; height: 19px; max-width: 19px; max-height: 19px; display: none;"></span><span class="stArrow"><span class="stButton_gradient stHBubble" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="stBubble_hcount">3</span></span></span></span></span></span>

<span class="st_twitter_hcount" st_url="https://critter.co" st_title="Do not overrate what you have received, nor envy others. He who envies others does not obtain peace of mind. - Buddha" st_via="CritterCoApp" displaytext="share" st_processed="yes"><span style="text-decoration:none;color:#000000;display:inline-block;cursor:pointer;" class="stButton"><span><span class="stMainServices st-twitter-counter" style="background-image: url(https://ws.sharethis.com/images/twitter_counter.png);">&nbsp;<img src="https://ws.sharethis.com/images/check-big.png" style="position: absolute; top: -7px; right: -7px; width: 19px; height: 19px; max-width: 19px; max-height: 19px; display: none;"></span><span class="stArrow"><span class="stButton_gradient stHBubble" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="stBubble_hcount">2</span></span></span></span></span></span>
```

Comment: in question,you wrote twitter is working,but later you are saying that twitter is not working while fb is..........

Comment: Thanks, Michel, fixed.

Comment: Pre-filling the message does not work any more for Facebook – the user has to actively type it in themselves.